How to Create SQL Query to Count Status Values Grouped by Remarks
I have two tables, master and Details, and I need to generate a report that counts the occurrences of each status value for each remark.
Here's the structure of my tables:
Table: master
m_id (Primary Key)
remarks (TEXT)

Table: Details
d_id
m_id (foreign key referencing master.m_id)
item
status

Here are some sample data inserts:
-- Inserting into master table
INSERT INTO master(m_id, remarks) VALUES(1, 'Remarks1');
INSERT INTO master(m_id, remarks) VALUES(2, 'Remarks2');

-- Inserting into Details table
INSERT INTO Details(d_id, m_id, item, status) VALUES(1, 1, 'Item1', 1);
INSERT INTO Details(d_id, m_id, item, status) VALUES(2, 1, 'Item2', 2);
INSERT INTO Details(d_id, m_id, item, status) VALUES(3, 1, 'Item3', 2);
INSERT INTO Details(d_id, m_id, item, status) VALUES(4, 1, 'Item3', 3);

INSERT INTO Details(d_id, m_id, item, status) VALUES(5, 2, 'Item1', 3);
INSERT INTO Details(d_id, m_id, item, status) VALUES(6, 2, 'Item2', 3);
INSERT INTO Details(d_id, m_id, item, status) VALUES(7, 2, 'Item3', 2);

Desired output:



Remarks
Status1_count
Status2_count
Status3_count




Remarks1
1
2
1


Remarks2
0
1
2



Tried using CASE. But here column name is dynamic.

What do you mean by "column name is dynamic"? Should this only mean the status can differ, but at least the number of columns is always the same? Or don't you even know how many columns (how many different status values) can/will appear? Anyway, such tasks can far better be done using your application rather than in SQL.

For you requirement to generate the column dynmaic you would need to use the dynamic query concept.
First generate the list of columns and then use the cross tab concept https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/tablefunc.html#:~:text=The%20crosstab%20function%20produces%20one,value%20fields%20from%20these%20rows in order to construct the data.
If you can share your current query then it will be helpful to get the proper result.

@JonasMetzler Such tasks can be done in a very clean and effective way using SQL + JSON

I assume that the number of status values may vary and become quite big. So I would suggest dynamic approach with a single JSON column per remarks with StatusX_count as attributes.
select remarks, json_object_agg(stcnt, cnt)
from
(
  select remarks, format('Status%s_count', status) stcnt, count(*) cnt
  from master join details using (m_id)
  group by remarks, status
) t
group by remarks;




remarks
status_count




Remarks1
{ "Status1_count" : 1, "Status3_count" : 1, "Status2_count" : 2 }


Remarks2
{ "Status3_count" : 2, "Status2_count" : 1 }



DB-Fiddle demo

You could use conditional aggregation...
--    S Q L :
Select      m.remarks, 
            Count(CASE WHEN d.status = 1 THEN 1 END) AS status1_cnt,
            Count(CASE WHEN d.status = 2 THEN 1 END) AS status2_cnt,
            Count(CASE WHEN d.status = 3 THEN 1 END) AS status3_cnt, 
            Count(CASE WHEN d.status = 4 THEN 1 END) AS status4_cnt
From        master m
Inner Join details d ON( d.m_id = m.m_id )
Group By    m.remarks

/*    R e s u l t : 
remarks   status1_cnt  status2_cnt  status3_cnt  status4_cnt
--------  -----------  -----------  -----------  -----------
Remarks1            1            2            1            0
Remarks2            0            1            2            0    */

See the fiddle here.

Yes, they write they con do that, but their question was how to do this "dynamic" (I guess this means for an unknown amount and for unknown different status values).

@JonasMetzler True, there is a remark of using case but we don't not how. Since the "dynamic" columns are actualy different statuses - I was assuming that there are not too many of them for conditional aggregation which is more readable and mainainable then the alternative CrossTab() function. In my experience the number of Integer statuses in a table very rarely is biger then 8 and in most cases it was between 4 and 6. There could be an issue if OP don't want to show columns with count of zero, though. That would be a bit odd in my opinion, but yes - that could be an issue.
